# How to test that block is run on a CoroutineDispatcher if it's invoked via launch(dispatcher) {...}

Tags: kotlin, executorservice, kotlinx.coroutines

We've recently started using coroutines on our Android application. All's gone fine and dandy, until someone wrote something roughly equivalent to the following function:

```
fun example(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher, block: () -> Unit) {
    launch(dispatcher) {
        block()
    }
}
```

We'd like to write a test that verifies that `block` is executed using `dispatcher`.

We've tried the following, but this doesn't work because we get a NullPointerException because `dispatcher.parentContext` is not mocked. I'm loathe to mock it, because we don't care what context it's executed in, just that it's executed:

```
@Test
fun `test that doesn't work`() {
    val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = mock()
    val block: () -> Unit = mock()

    // fails here, specifically on the call to `launch` in example()
    example(dispatcher, block)

    val captor = argumentCaptor<Runnable>()
    verify(dispatcher).dispatch(any(), captor.capture())
    verify(block, never()).invoke()

    captor.firstArgument.run()
    verify(block).invoke()
}
```

We've come upon this as an option, but it still doesn't feel right:

```
@Test
fun `test that works but doesn't feel right`() {
    val executor: ExecutorService = mock()
    val block: () -> Unit = mock()

    example(executor.asCoroutineDispatcher(), block)

    val captor = argumentCaptor<Runnable>()
    verify(executor).execute(captor.capture())
    verify(block, never()).invoke()

    captor.firstArgument.run()
    verify(block).invoke()
}
```

Can anyone come up with anything better?

EDIT:

Notable dependencies are as follows:

```
com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:1.5.0
org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.22.5
junit:junit:4.12
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.30
```

Comment: I had a rough time setting up the environment to match your deps. It would save a lot of time if you add them explicitly.

Comment: It actually fails because your mocked context returns `null` for `plus(Context)`, violating that method's not-null contract.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik fixed the dependencies

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik as a response to your second comment, what I'd _like_ to do is take some existing `CoroutineDispatcher` implementation and mock it, checking that its `dispatch` method is called. However, all official implementations, as far as I can tell, have `final` `dispatch` methods, and mocking final methods is a bad idea.

Comment: Well it's true, Kotlin's language design means it's harder to mock random stuff which wasn't designed to be subclassed. I guess you'll need a more elaborate solution, like a custom mock implementation of a `CoroutineDispatcher`.

Comment: @MikeHoller did you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: Sadly I have not, which turns me off coroutines quite a bit if I have to write my own testable wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

Since `launch` returns a `Job`, you need to wait for its completion to be able to verify anything that has been done.

You can do that in two ways:

Since you are `launch`ing a coroutine, your actual unit test might be finished before the launch's execution is done. You need to wait for its execution to make sure your test does not finish early. You can do that in multiple ways.

1. Change your function signature to return the Job from launch (e.g.`fun example(dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher, block: () -> Unit) = launch(dispatcher) { ...`. This way you can call `.join()` on the `example` function to wait for its completion.

   2. Keep an internal `var exampleJob:Job? = null`, and set it using the execution of launch, e.g. `exampleJob = launch { ...}`. This way, in your tests, you can use `exampleJob.join()` to wait for its completion and do your verifications afterwards.

Bonus solution:

You can also use [MockK](https://mockk.io/) to `verifyWithTimeout` your unit-test. This way, your unit test waits for the verification to finish.

Comment: You shouldn't change your method's signature simply because there is no other way around to test it. And the bonus is as unhelpful as your first two solutions. You cant decide how long is enough plus waiting for verification?!

Answer (score 0):

I assume your function uses `WithContext` or a coroutine builder that can be called at a top level like `runBlocking`. In order to test it, we can make use of the Mockk library and capture the Thread name when `block` is executed as follow

```
every { block() } answers { threadName = Thread.currentThread().name }
```

then we can use it to check the name of the thread:

```
// for Dispatchers.Default and Dispatchers.IO as they share the same thread pool
assert(threadName!!.startsWith("DefaultDispatcher-worker-"))
```

In your case, your test can be like this:

```
@Test
fun `test that works but doesn't feel right`() {
    val executor = Dispatchers.IO
    val block: () -> Unit = mock()
    // The following two lines help you determine on which thread your coroutine is runing
    var threadName = ""
    every { block() } answers { threadName = Thread.currentThread().name }

    example(executor, block)
    // Checking if the coroutine is running on the thread with DefaultDispatcher-worker as name. If it's the case, we are using Dispatchers.IO or Dispatchers.Default
    assert(threadName.startsWith("DefaultDispatcher-worker-")) 
}
```

If you want to check if the code is running on `UnconfinedDispatcher`, replace

```
assert(threadName.startsWith("DefaultDispatcher-worker-"))
```

by

```
assert(threadName.startsWith("Test worker"))
```

and so on.